# why do we need to capture reference for a reference in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, pass-by-reference

Consider this:

```
class TestLambda {
public:
    std::vector<char> data;
};

void test_lambda(TestLambda& obj) {
    [=]() mutable {
        obj.data.push_back(0x01);
    }();
}

int main() {
    TestLambda tst;
    tst.data.push_back(0x99);
    test_lambda(tst);

    // tst.data is unchanged at this point

    return 0;
}
```

After calling `test_lambda` what I expected was to see the change in `tst.data`, but this is not the case. To see the changes, I had to create lambda passing again a reference of `obj`, ie. `[&obj]()`.

Why do we need this? I mean, again a reference?

`obj` is already a reference. Then, `lambda` is capturing `obj` by copying it. So, `obj` within the `lambda` itself is not a reference? Why?

Could somebody explain me this? Thank you.

Comment: a reference is an alias, so its just another lvalue. in virtually all situations, it behaves no different from the variable it is referencing. Make a copy of the original, or a copy of the alias, its still a copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used in the right hand side of an assigment, a reference works just as a "normal" variable. Whenever you define a lambda capturing by value, the lambda owns a copy of the outer variables, as if the lambda started with these lines:

```
auto my_inner_variable = my_outer_reference;
auto my_inner_other_variable = my_outer_other_variable;
```

If you want the reference to "remain" a reference, you have to capture it by reference, thus instructing the compiler to emit code like this:

```
auto& my_inner_variable = my_outer_reference;
auto& my_inner_other_variable = my_outer_other_variable; // if we instructed to capture everything by reference
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the draft standard *§5.1.2/p15 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that is not of the form & identifier or & identifier initializer.**
>   For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is
>   declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members
>   is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the type of the
>   corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an
>   object, or the referenced type otherwise.** [ Note: If the captured
>   entity is a reference to a function, the corresponding data member is
>   also a reference to a function. — end note ] A member of an anonymous
>   union shall not be captured by copy.

Consequently, in:

```
void test_lambda(TestLambda& obj) {
    [=]() mutable {
        obj.data.push_back(0x01);
    }();
}
```

`obj` is captured by copy, and thus you get rightfully the described results. In other words this is the behaviour that the standard dictates for `[=]` capture default.

Comment: How could "implicitly" capture obj? []() {} gives me "not captured" error. +1.

Comment: I think OP understands what `[=]` means. I think the question is about types of captured entities: why captured reference makes a copy. Capturing could be demonstrated as: `auto objCopy = obj;` inside lambda, should it be `TestLambda objCopy = obj;`  or `TestLambda& objCopy = obj;`? @Lodo's answer addresses this even if not perfectly clear

Comment: @AndyT Right. My lack of knowledge was what was happening when doing TestLambda objCopy = obj; Now I see why it does not remain as a reference.

Comment: *"...or the referenced type otherwise"* is the sentence that should be emphasised here

Answer (score 0):

Your function `test_lambda` contains a nested lambda function. Inside `test_lambda`, the reference `obj` refers to `tst` in main. Then you call an anonymous lambda function that captures by value. Inside the lambda function `obj` is an copy of the `obj` that was inside test_lambda. Why not simply write:

```
void test_lambda(TestLambda& obj) {
   obj.data.push_back(0x01);
}
```

What you are doing now is perhaps illustrated by

```
void test_lambda(TestLambda& obj) {
    [=]() mutable {
        objCopy.data.push_back(0x01);
    }();
}
```

where `objCopy` was created by the value capturing lambda.

Comment: I wrote this snippet to be able to express my question. The question is not how can i write function to change obj.